# How to create random key in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Each element in list must have a unic key. So how can create this key?

I did function which return keys like this:

1. QV8938
2. XN0210
3. DC7389
4. DC8376
5. HA8357
   etc. With random. Is it normal to create such keys?

Comment: 1. It's not about react but javascript. 2. We don't know how you generate these. 3. It's probably not good because they can collide. 4. Usually packages that do that for you are used like `uuid`

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you just looking to generate a random string of characters in that format in JavaScript with the acceptable small chance you'll randomly get the same value twice? Are you looking for alternative styles, in which case we'd need to know how many users are generating IDs on how many machines at a given time, which would help design an algorithm that is more likely to be unique for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it normal to create such keys?

No, and it's not a good idea. Read the [Lists and Keys documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

There are three separate problems with random keys:

1. If they're random, you might end up with the same key on more than one item. (You can mitigate this problem with a sufficiently-powerful random generator like ones used for GUIDs, though.)
2. You'll cause unnecessary work committing to the DOM for something that hasn't actually changed when its key changes.
3. You'll cause display errors by *not* re-committing to the DOM when something *does* change but its key doesn't change.

Instead, derive your keys from the data for the items being displayed, which is always possible, even if it means you have to create artificial keys for them and then reuse those artificial keys.

You might be tempted to use array indexes as keys. [That's not a good idea either in almost any case](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/) *(that post is linked from the documentation above)*. The only exception is a static array of static items — nothing in it is ever modified, nor does its order ever change; in that one case, using the index as a key is okay.